# Searching for tutorial for securing Restful using Jersy TLS, OAUTH

Tags: java, https, oauth, restful-authentication

I am learning Restful Web Service and i am searching for Tutorials which can help me to learn how to build secured Restful using https/TLS ,OAUTH 1,2 and other tools
If you could you please recommend tutorials or videos books anything which will help me.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials will generally teach you how to do a specific thing (but they can teach the wrong concept).  I would suggest first understanding the concepts.  I found this book to be very useful:
RESTful Web Services (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do)

The book does have complex problems and solves them in numerous languages, Java being one.  (It is not fully up to date, so reading up on Jersey 2 might be needed as well to take full advantage of the new features).

Comment: Important point in this Answer, but the Question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.